# Getting integer from an edit text and using it in a for statement

Tags: android

I created an 2 activities, Home and timetable. In the home activity, i have a button which opens the timetable page. When the user clicks on the button, the timetable activity opens. In the OnCreate method of timetable activity, i have an AlertDialog which is used to collect a number (I know i can use a Number Picker here, but i prefer this).

Here is my timetable Activity Code:

```
private View view;
private int maxLength = 2;
TableLayout table; 
private int testint;
LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater;
Inflater inflater;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_time_table, null);

    // Alert Dialog for Collecting Number of Courses Offered 
    setNumberOfCourses();

    ViewGroup root2 = (ViewGroup) root.findViewById(R.id.TimeTableSetter);

    for (int i=0; i<testint; i++){
        view = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.timetablerowitem, root2, false);
        root2.addView(view);    
    }
    return root;
}

private void setNumberOfCourses() {
    AlertDialog.Builder setNum = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    setNum.setTitle ("Number of Courses");
    setNum.setMessage("How Many Courses do you offer");

    final EditText CourseNos = new EditText(getActivity());

    CourseNos.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

    CourseNos.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength )});
    setNum.setView(CourseNos);

    setNum.setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int goBtn) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String CourseValue = CourseNos.getText().toString();
        testint = Integer.parseInt(CourseValue);
        }
    });

    setNum.setNegativeButton("Back", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int bkbtn) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent backHome = new Intent(getActivity(), Jack_heart.class );
            startActivity(backHome);
        }
    });

    setNum.show();
}
```

--- In this activity, i am creating a certain number of rows based on the value entered by the user in the alertDialog.

Everything works fine, as a matter of fact if i replaced the testint in the for statement with an integer lets say 4, four timetablerows are created. But when i use testint, and i insert a value in  the edit text field, nothing happens.

I dont know what the problem is.

Comment: int a= Integer.ParseInt(youedittext.getText().toString);

Comment: @NitinMisra I think i have already done that, check my code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in your `for-loop` is called at time of `createView`.
Move your `for-loop` code outside of create view to a seperate method

```
    public void updateTable(){
   //you might need to remove existing childs before updating table
    ViewGroup root2 = (ViewGroup) root.findViewById(R.id.TimeTableSetter);

        for (int i=0; i<testint; i++){


            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.timetablerowitem, root2, false);

             root2.addView(view);   
        }
    }
```

Now call this table from your `onClick` method when you have a new testInt -

```
setNum.setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int goBtn) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        String CourseValue = CourseNos.getText().toString();

        testint = Integer.parseInt(CourseValue);

        updateTable();



        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. had to change getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState) to getLayoutInflater(null). Hope it wont cause any issues in future.

Comment: While in `onCreateView`, you can store a reference of `inflater` as field so as to use it later in other methods.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you. add this in xml file in editText box

```
 android:inputType="number"
```

this intakes only numbers instead of any charecters..